# BONOBO GIT Server Login returns to same page

Tags: git, bonobo

I installed bonobo Git Server on Windows 8 server,
 its Showing login page. As per the login instruction the username and password is admin,admin.

after that its return to the same login page again.

Please tell me the solution for same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just installing it for the first time and run into the same issue. Version 5 was only released around a week ago and I noticed a similar issue has been raised on their GitHib page, see [Bonobo 5.0.0 Unable to login on Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS 8](https://github.com/jakubgarfield/Bonobo-Git-Server/issues/339). While I couldn't see a link to previous versions on their page I found it's still available on their server:

[Bonobo Git Server Version 4.0.0](https://jakubgarfield.blob.core.windows.net/bonobo/Bonobo.Git.Server.4.0.0.zip)

Installing that has resolved the issue so maybe you can try that as well until the issue is resolved in version 5. I found it was necessary to delete the version 5 files before unzipping the version 4 release, just unzipping over the top didn't work.